# Electron multiple window communication

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to build an electron app where multiple window will load urls from a pool of urls, and send back information using ipcRender.

My design looks something like this:

main.js:

```
function foo(){
    var urls = [ urls ....]

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        var window = new BrowserWindow({
            webPreferences: {
                preload: "preload.js"
            }
        })

        window.webContents.on("did-finish-load"), function(){
            window.webcontents.executeJavascript("helloWorld()")
            console.log(i)
        }

        // Omitted some checks
        window.load(urls.shift())
    }

    ipc.on('helloworld', function(event, data){
        console.log(data)
        if (urls.length >= 1){
            event.returnValue = urls.shift();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = 'done'
        }
    })
}
app.on('ready', foo)
```

preload.js

```
helloWorld = function(){
    var result = ipc.sendSync('helloWorld', 'hey there')
    if (result != done){
        window.location = result;
    }
}
```

The output:
    2hey there
    2hey there
    2hey there
    ....

The current code kind of worked: it keeps on loading the url once the page finish loading and executes the helloWorld function, and I was able to get the data from the ipcMain.

However, only 1 out of 3 window are doing this, instead of my expectation of 3 windows working sort of asynchronously. The other 2 windows are just loading the first website and doesn't do anything else.

Why is this happening, and what should be a proper way to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `window` variable within callback function for `did-finish-load` does not contain what you think: it always points to the last created BrowserWindow instance.

[Why? Scope.](http://www.datchley.name/loop-variable-gotcha/)

Since you're using Electron, you should be able to fix this easily by declaring `window` with `let` instead of `var`.